# Using * to glob within an input file, or using multiple wildcards in input, then using only one wildcard for output?

Tags: snakemake

Is there a way to write a rule so that I don't need to use the wildcards for all inputs/outputs or can I use a "*" to glob rather than using wildcards??  I want to symlink a file that is autocreated in subfolders, to the main directory.

This is the error I get when trying to run the Snakemake:

```
WildcardError in line 42 of snakemake_guppy_basecall/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'failpass'
```

```
import glob

configfile: "config.yaml"

inputdirectory=config["directory"]
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards(inputdirectory+"/{sample}.fast5", followlinks=True)
print(SAMPLES)

wildcard_constraints:
    sample="\w+\d+_\w+_\w+\d+_.+_\d"


##### target rules #####
rule all:
    input:
       #expand('basecall/{sample}/sequencing_summary.txt', sample=SAMPLES),
       "qc/multiqc.html"


rule make_indvidual_samplefiles:
    input:
        inputdirectory+"/{sample}.fast5",
    output:
        "lists/{sample}.txt",
    shell:
        "basename {input}  > {output}"


rule guppy_basecall_persample:
    input:
        directory=directory(inputdirectory),
        samplelist="lists/{sample}.txt",
    output:
        summary="basecall/{sample}/sequencing_summary.txt",
        directory=directory("basecall/{sample}/"),
    params:
        config["basealgo"]
    shell:
        "guppy_basecaller -i {input.directory} --input_file_list {input.samplelist} -s {output.directory} -c {params} --compress_fastq -x \"auto\" --gpu_runners_per_device 3 --num_callers 2 --chunks_per_runner 200"

rule guppy_linkfastq:
    input:
        #glob_wildcards("basecall/{sample}/*/*.fastq.gz"),
        "basecall/{sample}/{failpass}/{runid}.fastq.gz",
    output:
        "basecall/{sample}.fastq.gz",
    shell:
        "ln -s {input} {output}"

rule fastqc_pretrim:
    input:
        #"basecall/{sample}/{failpass}/{runid}.fastq.gz",
        "basecall/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        html="qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}.html",
        zip="qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}_fastqc.zip" # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file. If not using multiqc, you are free to choose an arbitrary filename
    params: ""
    log:
        "logs/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}.log"
    threads: 1
    wrapper:
        "v0.75.0/bio/fastqc"

rule multiqc:
    input:
        #expand("basecall/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
        expand("qc/fastqc_pretrim/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        "qc/multiqc.html"
    params:
        ""  # Optional: extra parameters for multiqc.
    log:
        "logs/multiqc.log"
    wrapper:
        "0.77.0/bio/multiqc"
```

I am trying to create a pipeline that does: Get Nanopore f5 sequence files -> run guppy basecaller GPU mode ->  use resulting fastq files to run FASTQC -> run multiQC for everything

Comment: You will need to use a lambda function on the input. See https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/7184/mix-globbing-and-wildcards-when-specifying-rule-input

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was getting close, but since not all samples generate output, I think I have to use "Data dependent conditional execution". https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution